# Error refering to $this from a .tpl file in opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: opencart, loader

using vqmod i inject this code in header.tpl.

```
<?php if ($this->customer->isLogged()){ if($this->customer->getCustomerGroupId()!=1) { ?>
              //show something

<?php } ?>
```

It worked fine in opencart 1.5.6.1 But now I updated to 2.0.3.1  and I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Loader::$customer in C:\UniServerZ\www\opencart-2.0.3.1\upload\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-catalog_view_theme_default_template_common_header.tpl
```

Is there a way to refer to $this from a .tpl file in 2.0.3.1 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call customer class from tpl, you have do this in `header.php,` 
store the data in to the `$this->data[]` and use it in the tpl file. That will be the right procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to user any library file in .tpl file in OC then you have to create instance of that class first then you can access it, try this one

```
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->isLogged()
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest opencart(ver 2.x) remove $this concept. so you will directly using

$customer->isLogged()